# Unity SpriteRenderer set Material in script

Tags: unity-game-engine, components, sprite

I just want to set the material of my sprite renderer in my script. How can I do that?
So I want to set the material of the Sprite Renderer in code but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the object/new material in the inspector by dragging and dropping your sprite renderer and the material to switch it to

edit:

```
public GameObject object;
public Material newMaterial;
//...
object.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material = newMaterial;
```

Comment: But in the sprite Renderer, there is a field with material